# MLFlow creates a new experiment run when logging manually along with autolog

Tags: metrics, mlflow, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using MLFlow to log metrics and artefacts in the AzureML workspace. With `autolog`, tensorflow training metrics are available in the experiment run in the AzureML workspace. Along with auto-logging of metrics - I want to log extra metrics and plots in the same experiment run. Doing it with MLFlow - it is creating a new experiment run.

**Auto logging:**

`mlflow.autolog()`

**Manual logging:**

`mlflow.log_metric(f"label-A", random.randint(80, 90))`

[image]

**Expected:**
Manually logged metrics are available in the same experiment run.

Comment: Are you performing both the logging steps within the same context i.e. `with mlflow.start_run() as run:` - inside this block? If not, you will need to retrieve the `run_id` of the first context and pass it while rerunning the context as `with mlflow.start_run(run_id) as run:`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the module method call `mlflow.log_metric` to log the metrics, use the client `MlflowClient` which takes run_id as the parameter.

Following code logs the metrics in the same `run_id` passed as the parameter.

```py
from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient
from azureml.core import Run

run_id = Run.get_context(allow_offline=True).id
MlflowClient().log_metric(run_id, "precision", 0.91)
```